# The provided web push applicationServerKey is not valid

Tags: subscribe, web-push

I am trying to subscribe to web push via the function below.

```
function postSubscriptionBo() {
  return navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js')
  .then(function(registration) {
    const subscribeOptions = {
      userVisibleOnly: true,
      applicationServerKey: APPLICATION_SERVER_KEY
    };

    return registration.pushManager.subscribe(subscribeOptions);
  })
  .then(function(pushSubscription) {
    console.log('Received PushSubscription: ', JSON.stringify(pushSubscription));
    return pushSubscription;
  });
}
```

These are the current steps: 
 1. Get the **application server key** from Firebase console > cloud messaging tab > **server key** 
 2. Encoded application server key with **window.btoa(server key)** 
 3. Removed tailing = from the server key
 4. Browser throws exception: The provided web push applicationServerKey is not valid.

Suggestions on what I am doing wrong here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the cloud messaging tab instead of using the server key, after generating a Web Push certificates public key (at the bottom of the same cloud messaging tab) and adding it instead of the server key, it worked.

Comment: But i got error `MismatchSenderId` when I run send message via Postman.

`
curl --request POST \
  --url https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send \
  --header 'Authorization: key=xxx' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{ 
  "to": "xxx",
    "priority": "high",
    "notification": {
        "title": "Title",
        "body" : "First Notification",
        "text": "Text"
    }
}'
`

Comment: also make sure to copy your public key-value by hand. copying by the firebase's click to copy feature only copies the key.

Comment: Your answer is a bit unclear. Could you rewrite it, maybe by splitting it up in two or more sentences?