React+Firebase: Registration failed - push service error
I'm trying to implement push notifications to my react web app. The permission is granted, but token isn't being generated. I'm using public VAPID key. I'm using brave browser and my app is running in docker.
If I use private VAPID key the permission isn't granted and the error is:

Error generating token: InvalidAccessError: Failed to execute 'subscribe' on 'PushManager': The provided applicationServerKey is not valid.

All environment variables seem to be right. here is a code snippet from . To be honest I'm quite unfamiliar with JS.
async function requestPermission() {
    const permission = await Notification.requestPermission();

    if (permission === "granted") {
        try {
            const token = await getToken(messaging, {
                vapidKey: VITE_APP_VAPID_KEY,
            });

            console.log("Token generated:", token);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error generating token:", error);
        }
    } else if (permission === "denied") {
        alert("You denied the notification permission");
    }
}

I tried changing the keys, but it's not producing any results.

Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60211741/209103 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77241230/fcm-js-client-provided-applicationserverkey-is-not-valid?
